# Squid transparent proxy for HTTPS / SSL trafic

Tags: iptables, squid

I am trying to configure Squid as transparent proxy, I followed below steps to configure

**Downloaded Squid 3.5 from the website, As Squid 3.1 will not support for ssl bump**

```
./configure --enable-linux-netfilter --enable-icap-client --enable-ssl --with-filedescriptors=65536 --with-large-files --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/squid --srcdir=. --datadir=${prefix}/share/squid --sysconfdir=/etc/squid
make
make install
```

SSL has been enabled for Squid, I can check using

```
squid -v 
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.2
Service Name: squid
configure options:  '--enable-linux-netfilter' '--enable-icap-client' '--enable-ssl' '--with-filedescriptors=65536' '--with-large-files' '--prefix=/usr' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libexecdir=/lib/squid' '--srcdir=.' '--datadir=/share/squid' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid' 'CPPFLAGS=-I../libltdl' --enable-ltdl-convenience
```

*Every thing is good till now*

I have created a certificate in `/etc/squid/cert/squid.pem` .

When I edit `squid.conf` to

```
http_port 3128
https_port 3130 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/squid/cert/squid.pem
```

only `http_port` with `3128` is running

```
netstat -nap | grep 3128
tcp6       0      0 :::3128                 :::*                    LISTEN      2802/squid
```

but `https_port 3130` is updating and even accepting certificates

```
#netstat -nap | grep 3130
#
```

I have tried to use `http_port` with `ssl-bump`:

```
squid -z
2015/03/06 19:52:11| FATAL: Unknown http_port option 'ssl-bump'.
FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

I have made to changes to `iptables` for redirecting port 80 to 3128 and 443 to 3130:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3130
```

Please let me know why am not able to add `ssl-bump` in `https_port`.

Comment: --enable-ssl-crtd is maybe missing in your configure list of options

Comment: Ohh !I will enable it BTW is there any way to enable after installation or do i have to start from **./configure**

Comment: It is not compiled in your software, so it will never be available. So start at configure, sorry !

Comment: I will do that no prob ..Thanks for your suggestion !

Comment: You may also be missing `--with-openssl` from the ./configure flags.